# Getting console error - Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main after upgrading Karate to 1.4.0 from 1.3.1 in Karate

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, karate

[image: Karate 1.4.0 update error after running feature file in Eclipse]

Getting console error - Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main. Issue in eclipse IDE. Same feature file is running ok with 1.3.0 and 1.3.1 versions.